# What do you call the process of unwinding a piece of adhesive tape?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call the process of unwinding a piece of adhesive tape? [image]Like so.

Can I use the verb *uncoil*. For example:

> Please **uncoil** a piece of the tape, but don't take it off.

What is the most natural way to say that?

Comment: Maybe ***peel*** *(off) a strip of tape*. *Uncoil* is typically used with rope or something similar.

Comment: I reeled off a length of tape.

Comment: "Peel off" is closer than "reel off" if it's adhesive tape, because of the force needed to separate it.